# Prevent Users From Seeing Requested URL and String Parameters

Tags: php, html, url, encryption

In my site, I am submitting information information that cannot be tampered with. Is there a way that I can prevent users from seeing the URL my app is requesting? In Google Chrome, it is very easy for users to see this.

I am submitting data to another website. They encrypt the data in their end but there isn't a way to encrypt the string parameters before and while they are being transmitted. This makes it easy for users to just copy the requested URL, change around the parameters, and do as they please. What options do I have to encrypt the string parameters?

Comment: If you're submitting it to someone else and you want to encrypt it, they're going to have to decrypt it. You should be asking them what options you have for encryption.

Comment: Submit the form with method=post, it's not encryption, but it won't be visible

Comment: @B Rad C, it will be just as visible with POST as it is with GET.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent them from seeing the URL if you are making the request from their client. You also can't trust anything on the client, so you can't encrypt something on the client.

Is there any reason you can't just send the data to your server, validate it, then forward it along to the target server? I'd say that is the correct option.

Comment: The app is an HTML5 based game. It uses http://gmscoreboard.com/ for the highscores. As far as I know, there isn't a way to validate the users score from the server.

Comment: Well if you can't validate the user score on the server there's little you can do. Any one can send any score he wants.

Comment: I just looked at gmscoreboard.com. It is in no way secure. Any one knowing your tagid (posted with each request) can send any score he wants to their server. He doesn't even need to play the game, just call the handle_score.php url.

Answer (score 0):

Dear user you can encrypt the url with md5 & mysql database
if you need random urls for every request

check
for more information its verry simple

https://www.php.net/md5

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

with the random function pretty simple

i hope you get the idea or you can just use the post method and store data on the mysql database

and once its on the final step you can make it run in the background as all the data will not be seen by the user. and make sure in production version of website you put on that php file

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
```

Have a nice day